# How to unit test the logic of MapGet in IEndpointRouteBuilder?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, .net-6.0

I am currently having troubles how to unit test the following code:

```
private static void RegisterGet(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
{
    endpoints.MapGet("/myAddress", async context => 
    { 
       await SomeTestWorthyLogic(); 
    });
}
```

It is easy to test the registration of `MapGet`, or the logic of `SomeTestWorthyLogic()`, but in my code coverage report, the calling line `await SomeTestWorthyLogic();` remains untested / never called.

So I tried to to setup serveral ways with the `IApplicationBuilder` / `RequestDelegate` I mocked `HttpContext` or `HttpRequest` but I always end up having status code 404 from the `HttpResponse`, eventhough I called "/myAddress".
I also tried to locate the code where the 404 might come from, but even setting a functional breakpoint in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.MatchAsync` to debug with symbols didn't hit ("Enable Just my code" settings where correct)

Anyways I guess it should be easy to unit test it, but neither my co-works nor myself found a way.

Comment: You don't - the route is tested via a functional test; some things just aren't tested at a unit test level. OR you test the resource / controller at a unit test level.

Comment: This is because it's a delegate of MapGet. Are you trying to acheive 100% code coverage? This seems over the top to me. If your Action does something you need to test then extract that logic somewhere and test it. Either a separate component or call the delegate from a test

Comment: This cannot be tested with constrained isolating frameworks such as Moq, NSubstitute, FakeItEasy. But, theoretically, this is possible with the help of unconstrained frameworks such as TypeMock, JustMock, MS Fakes, Prig, Ionad.Fody, Pose, Harmony, MethodRedirect.

Comment: Yes, we usually have a coverage of 100% - And I know the discussion behind it. @AlexanderPetrov: I actually tried it with a "DefaultHttpContext" so a "real" request. Still couldn't figure out a working path. I'll try to find the source of this MatchAsync, maybe I find a way, to mock the right property in order to get it done.